# How can I make the record's value selected in a dropdown list in CakePHP?

Tags: drop-down-menu, cakephp-1.3

I want to show the right "employee" selected in the dropdown list. How can I do that?

It's in [CakePHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CakePHP)!

```
echo $form->input('employee_id',array('label' => 'Task Owner:', 'type'=>'select', 'options'=>$firstname));
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh well, it seems this line of code works on my Mac at home, so I guess I was just too tired to notice it on my Linux machine at work.

Thanks anyways !